# issue with search implemnetation with ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been working on a simple Laravel CRUD application. I want to implement search functionality to it, so I used ajax call for it. But my code is not working.

**web.php**

```
  Route::post('/search',[
     'as' => 'searchbox',
     'uses' => 'HomeController@postSearch'
     ]);
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function postSearch(Request $request)
    {
# code...
   $items = Item::where('title', 'like', '%' . 'title1' . '%')->paginate(10);
  // return response()->json(['msg-body'=>$request['body']],200);
    return view('welcome')->with(['items'=>$items]);

 }
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
Welcome
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <h4>Crud</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3">
          <form method="POST" action=>
            <input class="search" type ="text" name ="search" id="search" placeholder="search"  >

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">

            <a href="{{route('create')}}"class="btn btn-primary"  >Create new item</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th style="width: width="280px";">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($items as $item)
              <tr ng-model="search_query">
                <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->description}}</td>
                <td><a href="{{route('showdetails',['id'=>$item->id])}}" class="btn btn-info">show</a><a href="{{route('editdetails',['id'=>$item->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a><a href="{{route('delete',['id'=>$item->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var token = '{{Session::token()}}';
var url = '{{route('searchbox')}}';
</script>
{{ $items->render()}}
@endsection
```

**style.js**

```
 $('.search').on('change',function(){
 $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url:url,
        data:{body: $("#search").val(),_token:token}
    }).done(function(msg){
        console.log($("#search").val());
    })
  });
```

Can anyone suggest me...

Comment: what do you mean by "code not working". Please explain the issue or any error you are getting

Comment: what is the value of `url` variable in your `style.js` ? I think you have not initiated the url variable.

Comment: when I searched for some title it is not working.no change in the list

Comment: what about the value of url variable ? Is it set properly ? Check your console for any output

Comment: yeah I checked url.it is http://localhost:8000/search

Comment: are you using web Route middleware ? CSRF middleware might be causing the error.. Can you check XHR in Network tab in your browser's developer tool ?

Comment: no .I am not using middleware.I didn't get any error in my network tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128157/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-user3860618).

Answer (score 0):

Add `{!! csrf_field() !!}`, inside your `<form>..</form>` element.
All `post/put/patch` request should send csrf_token or request will fail.

Comment: added in script tag at the end of blade.php file

Answer (score 0):

check line

```
$items = Item::where('title', 'like', '%' . 'title1' . '%')->paginate(10);`,
```

i think its should be

```
$items = Item::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->input('body') . '%')->paginate(10);
```

Now you just searching for string `title1`

Comment: i tried with it.so just for static i implemented it.

Comment: So what do you get in network response or in your console?

Comment: in my network console iam getting search output as required.but mty page is nor redirecting to the url localhost:8000/search .so i am not getting any filtered data

Comment: my page is not directing after change .but in my network tab it is going to /search url .

Comment: Oh, thats because you using ajax request, ajax request doesnt redirect you to page, and i dont see any reason why you should do this - it will redirect after you enter 1 letter to input (as i see from your code); You should use:  a). normal form for this, b). get response from url using ajax, and print it to DOM. c). after getting response use `window.location.href=url + "?body=" + $("#search").val();` (bad idea without submit button)

Comment: `.done(function(msg){ console.log(msg); })` - will return search results to your console, using data in  `msg` you can update your HTML without event reloading page.

Comment: can you tell me how to implement that in js file?I am tried but I failed to create table with that response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128241/discussion-between-user3860618-and-kiberzauras).